# Understanding tensorflow text_classification.py

Tags: python, tensorflow

There is [text_classification.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification.py) example that classifies text by two methods (bow and rnn).

I am trying to understand what's actually going on here. First, let's look at `bag_of_words_model`. It runs `bow_encoder`. By running `bow_encoder` it defines the layer and the embedding vectors are continuously updated on every step of gradient descent? Then, it averages the vectors connects this via `W2` to the output. So here we have two `W` matrices. One from the input to embedding layer, the second from the averaged vector to the output (this architecture reminds me the word2vec model actually). Right?

The second model - `rnn_model`. It calls `embed_sequence`, `embed_sequence` similar to `rnn_model` but instead of averaging embedding vectors it concatenates them. Right?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: very similar to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033038/tensorflow-bow-encoder-explanation)